# Arithmetic operations inside the parenthesis javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, math, arithmetic-expressions

Hi Please help me to resolve this issue

```
    var str = '10+20-10-2';
    var numbers = str.replace(/ /g, '').split(/[-+*\/]/g);
    var operators = str.replace(/ /g, '').split(/\d*/g);
    operators.shift();        
    var result = +numbers[0];        
    for (var i = 0; i < operators.length - 1; i++) {
        result = eval( result + operators[i] + numbers[i + 1] );
    }        
    alert(result)​;
```

Above code is working fine , but when am trying to pass some other input like

```
 var str = '-(1)-(-2)';
    var str = '-1-(-1)';
    var str = '(-1)-2'  ;
```

not getting any result

Comment: If you're using eval anyways, how about `result = eval(str)`?

Comment: You’re trying to parse a non-regular (context-free) language with regular expressions. This is bound to fail.

Comment: your examples can be calculated with just `eval`: `eval('10+20-10-2') is 18`, `eval('-(1)-(-2)') is 1`. you don't need to "parse string" but using `eval` is not good approach.

Comment: oh fine . Is there any other approach to resolve this issue.

Comment: @Ruslan: There are some cases where `eval` is fine. I'd say this is one of them.

Answer (score 0):

I guess in your case, besides eval, you could also use

```
var result = parseFloat(numbers[0]);
```

and consequently

```
result = eval( result + operators[i] + parseFloat(numbers[i + 1]))
```

This is a bit more solid because it works only if the strings in numbers REALLY contain numbers, and will return `NaN` if they don't. Also, to be even more solid, you could go the long way and use a `switch` instruction:

```
switch(operators[i])
{
   case "+":
   etc.
}
```

Of course your solution is more elegant, but since it does not work for some reason, this might help you spot it. In you, I'd also check with a couple `alert()` functions the actual content of those splitted arrays. Sometimes regular expressions do not produce quite the output you'd expect them to.